# C# getters and setters method definition - beginner

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. i was going through a tutorial. and it shows how to create accesor-mutator to a variable as shown below;

```
public String var1 {

get {return "";}
set {someVar = value;}

}
```

1.) Can't i create getters and setter like created in java

```
public getVar() {return "";}
public setVar(String x){var=x;}
```

2.) What is `value` used in C# ?

Comment: @downvoter, drop some comment..

Comment: Just to add to the existing answers - it's not only easier to read, but downright *necessary* for some things - such as bindings in WPF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You can, but that's much more annoying to use, and ignores C# coding guidelines.
2. `value` is the implicit parameter to the setter.  It contains the value that the caller is setting the property to.  (the right side of the `Property = something` call)

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

1. Sure you can.  Properties in C# are designed to be syntactic sugar for just that.  Under the hood a property is little more than a get/set method.  It's just easier to create the two methods, it keeps the two methods in one place in the source code, it has simpler syntax for the caller, and properties that do nothing but just get/set a value are easier still to generate.
2. It's a keyword.  It is the value that is being passed into the method.  If someone enters `obj.var1 = "abc";` then `value` will be a reference to `"abc"`.

Comment: Note that while looking just like syntactic sugar, properties are still a different concept than just conventions for methods. Also, `value` is not a keyword, otherwise you wouldn’t be able to use `value` as a variable name anywhere else. It’s just a variable that is implicitely defined in the setter.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can do it like Java. But why? Property syntax allows a much better experience from the caller's point of view.

`value` is a pseudo-variable that you can use to set your internal variable with, etc. It's equivalent to `x` in your Java-like example.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can create getter setters as in java
example

```
int marks;
public void setMarks(int marks)
{
this.marks=marks;
}
public int getMarks()
{
return marks;
}
```